# Issue with multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, tracking

I am having an issue with this darn array. It was to post my info looking like this. Any ideas how to fix this?

```
prdpr=10.95^TBCC9^2^Shoes
prdsku=2.50^TDxa2^1^Pants
prdqn=7.50^Tasds^1^Hats
prdcatid=undefined^undefined^undefined^undefined
```

What it should look like is:

```
prdpr=10.95^2.50^7.50
prdsku=TBCC9^TDxa2^Tasds
prdqn=2^1^1
prdcatid=Shoes^Pants^Hats
```

Later I'll just string together for a URL

```
var advid = "xxx";
var oid = "xxx";
var amt = "20.95";

// This array I cannot mess with, this is just an example
var OrderDetails = new Array();
OrderDetails[0] = ['10.95','2.50','7.50'];
OrderDetails[1] = ['TBCC9','TDxa2','Tasds'];
OrderDetails[2] = ['2','1','1'];
OrderDetails[3] = ['Shoes','Pants','Hats'];

var prdpr = '';
var prdsku = '';
var prdqn = '';
var prdcatid = '';

for(var x = 0; x < OrderDetails.length; x++) {
    var delim = "";
    if(x == 0){
        delim = "";
    }  else{
        delim = "^";
    }

    prdsku += delim + OrderDetails[x][0];
    prdpr += delim + OrderDetails[x][1];
    prdqn += delim + OrderDetails[x][2];
    prdcatid += delim + OrderDetails[x][3];
}

var output = '<div>Product Sku=' + prdsku + 'Item Cost=' + prdpr + 'Quanty=' + prdqn + 'Category=' + prdcatid + '</div>';
document.write(output);
```

Comment: If you use the `{}` button or add four spaces before a line, it will be code blocked. You should edit your question and clean it up please.

Comment: A small note: try to avoid using `document.write` and instead manipulate the DOM directly.

Comment: @Dai, but also note that [dom is slower than document.write](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/innerhtml.html).

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand The article you linked to refers to `innerHTML`, not `document.write`. The two are different as `document.write` causes a complete reparsing of the document text, whereas `innerHTML` does not.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand I might be missing it, but no where in that link does it talk about `document.write`. I do see it using `innerHTML` though...

Comment: ah, thanks :-)  I though it `document.write(code)` was just `document.body.innerHTML += code`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var OrderDetails = new Array();
OrderDetails[0] = ['10.95','2.50','7.50'];
OrderDetails[1] = ['TBCC9','TDxa2','Tasds'];
OrderDetails[2] = ['2','1','1'];
OrderDetails[3] = ['Shoes','Pants','Hats'];

var delim = '^';

var prdpr = OrderDetails[0].join(delim);
var prdsku = OrderDetails[1].join(delim);
var prdqn = OrderDetails[2].join(delim);
var prdcatid = OrderDetails[3].join(delim);
```